# Problema para enlazar botones con backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone

Acabo de empezar a usar el framework  backbone.js usando `router` para generar urls en mi html.
Tengo 3 botones definidos asi

```
        <ul class="list-inline ">
            <li><button id="boton1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#vistade1">1</button></li>
            <li><button id="boton2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#vistade2">2</button></li>
            <li><button id="boton3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#vistade3">3</button></li>
        </ul>
```

y mi código del backbone es este

```
(function(){
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {

        "boton1/:id" : "vistauno",
        "boton2/:id" : "vistados",
        "boton3/:id" : "vistatres"
},

  vistauno: function (boton1) {
      console.log("estas intentando acceder a "+boton1);
},
  vistados: function (boton2) {
      console.log("estas intentando acceder a "+boton2);
},
  vistatres: function (boton3) {
      console.log("estas intentando acceder a "+boton3);
}

});
var Router = new Router(); 
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Me funciona cuando pongo la ruta `index.html#boton2` o `index.html#boton3`
a mano pero si le doy pulsando el botón no me funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las rutas en Backbone controlan lo que hace cuando cambia la URL en el navegador, tal como tú haces cuando la escribes "a mano".

Ni `button` ni `li` cambian por si mismos la URL en el navegador, eso lo hacen los tags `a`, o con eventos JavaScript (como menciona @Miquel).

Prueba con:

```
<li><a id="boton1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#boton1/1">1</a></li>
```

Si además quieres que se parezca a un botón sólo tendrás que cambiar su aspecto con CSS.

Fijate, de paso, en el "href", lo he puesto según el formato que tú das en las rutas de Backbone; `href="#vistade1"` no es una ruta que tengas controlada, según el código que has pegado.

Answer (score 1):

Te faltan definir los `events`:

```
events: {
    "click #boton1": "vistauno",
    "click #boton2": "vistados",
    "click #boton3": "vistatres"
  },
```

Además, cómo se ha comentado es importante añadir la librería `underscore.js` junto a `backbone.js`